# Eliminate graphic tearing

Tags: tearing

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  I have been able to get rid of tearing while using xbmc but I would like to get rid of it on youtube videos as well.  I installed compizconfig and tried some settings someone had recommended with no luck.  I am running an ATI/AMD graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use/install catalyst drivers for your graphics card, inside the Catalyst Control Center you'll find tearing setting under the monitor options folder that solves that.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had no idea that catalyst control center existed.  I clicked tear-free and now problem solved.  So simple but I never would have known.  Thanks again.